# wxPython: how to position extra widgets in the status bar?

Tags: user-interface, drop-down-menu, wxpython, statusbar

I managed to add a wx.Choice to a status bar by making the Choice its child, and theoretically it does display in the right area:
[image: Choice widget in status bar]
The problems:

1. As apparent, the Choice widget hides the status bar's text.
2. I can't find any way to position my Choice to the right-side of the
   window.

So as you can guess, my objective here is to align the Choice item on the right-side of the window, and to make sure that the status bar's text pane respects the Choice's presence.

Comment: Mike's answer in added link is awesome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737630/wxpython-how-to-set-widget-position-inside-statusbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Statusbar',size=(300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        status_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Get Statusbar Info')
        status_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_status)
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(2)
        w1 = self.statusbar.Size[0]
        w1= w1 - 50
        self.statusbar.SetStatusWidths([w1, -1])
        self.statusbar.SetMinHeight(30)
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Statusbar field 1')
        self.mychoices = wx.Choice(self.statusbar, wx.ID_ANY, choices=[("en"), ("it"), ("de")])
        self.mychoices.SetSelection(0)
        self.mychoices.SetPosition((w1+2, 2))
        self.Show()

    def on_status(self, event):
        print (self.statusbar.GetStatusText())
        print (self.mychoices.GetSelection())
        print (self.mychoices.GetString(self.mychoices.GetSelection()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: SetStatusWidths was giving me a field number mismatch but I managed to get it to work by only passing it [w1]. Thanks.
I also used mychoices.Size[0] instead of 50 to get the right width regardless of the wx.Choice's size.