# wxPython how to set widget position inside statusbar

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I would like to add two buttons inside the status bar, and I have them implemented as follows:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Constructor"""

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)


        # self.status_bar = self.CreateStatusBar(3)
        self.status_bar = self.CreateStatusBar(3)

        self.status_bar.SetStatusText("some text", 0)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.status_bar, -1, "button 1")
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.status_bar, -1, "button 2")
        self.status_bar.SetStatusWidths([-1, 200, 200])
        self.button1.SetPosition((self.status_bar.Size[0]-100, 0))
        self.button2.SetPosition((self.status_bar.Size[0]-200, 0))

        self.Refresh()
        self.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame(None, -1)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The problem is that: I do not know how to properly set the positions of the buttons.
For the above example, I have two slots for them already, but I can't put them in the slots. In stead, I have to use the "SetPosition" function to set the fix positions of the buttons, but once the window gets resized the button will stay there and will not be seen.

I was wondering if there is a easy way to set the position of the buttons inside the statusbar like we set the text using "self.status_bar.SetStatusText(self.button1, 1)" and "self.status_bar.SetStatusText(self.button2, 2)"

Thanks a lot!

===========================================================================

Thanks a lot to Mike Driscoll's answer, I have figured out the way to do it.
I'll post my solution as follows in case any one needs it.

```
import wx

class MyStatusBar(wx.StatusBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.StatusBar.__init__(self, parent)

        self.SetFieldsCount(3)
        self.SetStatusWidths([-1, 200, 200])
        self.sizeChanged = False
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, self.OnIdle)

        # Field 0 ... just text
        self.SetStatusText("some text", 0)

        # Field for buttons
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, 1001, "button 1")
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self, 1002, "button 2")

        # set the initial position of the checkbox
        self.Reposition()

    def OnSize(self, evt):
        evt.Skip()
        self.Reposition()  # for normal size events

        # Set a flag so the idle time handler will also do the repositioning.
        # It is done this way to get around a buglet where GetFieldRect is not
        # accurate during the EVT_SIZE resulting from a frame maximize.
        self.sizeChanged = True


    def OnIdle(self, evt):
        if self.sizeChanged:
            self.Reposition()


    # reposition the buttons
    def Reposition(self):
        rect1 = self.GetFieldRect(1)
        rect1.x += 1
        rect1.y += 1
        self.button1.SetRect(rect1)

        rect2 = self.GetFieldRect(2)
        rect2.x += 1
        rect2.y += 1
        self.button2.SetRect(rect2)

        self.sizeChanged = False


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Constructor"""

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

        self.status_bar = MyStatusBar(self)
        self.SetStatusBar(self.status_bar)

        self.Refresh()
        self.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame(None, -1)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to subclass wx.StatusBar itself, add the buttons and then catch the `wx.EVT_SIZE`. This way you catch resize events and can reposition the widgets as needed.

The wxPython demo has an example where it has a checkbox widget with the following method:

```
# reposition the checkbox
def Reposition(self):
    rect = self.GetFieldRect(1)
    rect.x += 1
    rect.y += 1
    self.cb.SetRect(rect)
    self.sizeChanged = False
```

The `self.GetFieldRect(1)` refers to the checkbox widget. You can use something like this for yours except that you will need to keep track of two widget's positions and update accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot